# Crossfilter stacked bar charts negate values

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am using a crossfilter2 with dcv3

My data is in a csv which i loaded into memory

**Original Data**

```
Day, ID
1, 2
1, 2
1, 2
2, 5
3, 6
4, 6
```

**Processed data**

```
Day, ID, target
1, 2, True
1, 2, True
1, 2, True
2, 5, False
3, 6, False
4, 6, False
```

Currently what i am trying to do is create a crossfilter stackedbar chart with 2 bars. If `ID == 2`, i consider it as one group, and `ID !=2` as another group. However, i cannot do it dynamically it in DC/crossfilter which results me having to preprocess the data to add a new column and work off the column as shown by my solution below.

Is there a better way?

```
var dimID = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.day; });

var id_stacked = dimID.group().reduce(
function reduceAdd(p, v) {
    p[v.target] = (p[v.target] || 0) + 1;
    return p;
},
function reduceRemove(p, v) {
    p[v.target] = (p[v.target] || 0) - 1;
    return p;
},
function reduceInitial() {
    return {};
    });

//Doing the stacked bar chart here
stackedBarChart.width(1500)
.height(150)
.margins({top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 50, left: 40})
.dimension(dimID)
.group(id_stacked, 'Others', sel_stack("True"))
.stack(id_stacked, 'Eeid of interest', sel_stack("False"))
```

This is my sel_stack function

```
function sel_stack(i) {
    return function(d) {
        return d.value[i] ? d.value[i] : 0;

    };
}
```

I am plotting a bar chart with x-axis being the day and the Y-axis being the frequency of `ID == 2` or `ID!=2` in a stacked bar chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to group by day and then stack by whether `ID===2`. Although dc.js will accept many different formats, often the trick is getting the data into the right shape.

You're on the right track, but you don't need the extra column in order to create stacks for "is 2" and "not 2". You can calculate it directly:

```
var dayDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.Day; }),
    idStackGroup = dayDimension.group().reduce(
        function add(p, v) {
            ++p[v.ID===2 ? 'is2' : 'not2'];
            return p;
        },
        function remove(p, v) {
            --p[v.ID===2 ? 'is2' : 'not2'];
            return p;
        },
        function init() {
              return {is2: 0, not2: 0};
        });
```

These are standard add/remove functions for reducing multiple values for each bin. You'll find [other variations where the name of the field is driven by the data](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#what-if-rows-contain-a-single-value-but-a-different-value-per-row). But here we know what fields will exist, so we can initialize them to zero in `init` and not worry about encountering new fields.

The `add` function is called when a row is added to the crossfilter or a filter changes so that a row is included; the `remove` function is called whenever a row is filtered out or removed from crossfilter. Since we're not worried about `undefined` <sup>(1)</sup> we can simply increment (`++`) and decrement (`--`) the values.

Finally we need accessors to pull these values out of the object. I think it's simpler to put the stack accessors inline - `sel_stack` was written for adding a dynamic number of stacks. (YMMV)

```
  .group(idStackGroup, 'Others', d => d.value.not2)
  .stack(idStackGroup, 'Eeid of interest', d => d.value.is2);
```

[image: two / not two stacks]

https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/fu4w96Lh/23/

<sup>(1)</sup> If you do any arithmetic on `undefined` it casts to `NaN` and `NaN` ruins all further calculations.

Comment: do you mind explaining your code better? especially on the add andremove functions? like what does the --p do? and why is it necessary

Comment: sure, I simplified the logic and added some explanation.